# Using Unit Testing to shortcut UI usage, does anyone else do this?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, .net-3.5

### Background

I admit, I don't use unit testing properly. I'm working on a monolithic Windows Forms application, and it was never written with Unit Testing in mind.

However, for the last 18 months or so, all my code has been written in a significantly more compartmentalised (read: good) manner. I have a Unit Testing class configured and it does a lot of complex wireup to simulate the user launching the software. It can spawn off forms and do all sorts of things. It's a bit like a mechanism to script our software usage.

### Instant results

Another thing I use it for (more and more often now) is to shortcut *usage* of the software altogether. F5 + running, plus navigating my way though the system (in the last 5 years, I've really gotten used to it) takes a lot of time.

My latest addition generates reports, it does all sorts of complex grouping and analysis. To test this, I've got a unit test which calls the code and spits out the results with `TestContext.WriteLine()`. It works extremely well, being able to right click the test and see results instantly. This is before I've bothered to mock up a UI for the functions yet.

Futhermore because the test scripts don't impact the final software, I am free to fire in data from different sources and manipulate it to make better tests.

### Pointless

When people write code and they're serious about testing (usually a demo or something), they'll write a test that asserts `x = y + 1` or something ridiculously simple. I need to check that massive hierarchies of data have grouped and sorted. Perhaps my text based output is enough, and this can be compared against an XML/text document in the future.

### Am I for real? (yes).

Do you use unit testing this way? I find it very useful, but I sometimes feel it's the wrong way to use them. As a general scriptable framework for the project, it's invaluable.

Thanks, Tom

P.S. Please don't think less of me because I might be abusing the system...

## Update

This is a broad question, the answer is spread over two answers, so I'll mark the first one. I assume this is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is fairly broad, but I did pick up on one thing I'll just expound on, in hopes that it helps.

One of the fundamentals of Unit testing is that you are testing a single expectation of a single operation in each test. The general upshot of that is that a single test should only have a single `Assert` in it, and it should be fairly 'simple'.

A single public method of a class in your application likely would be touched by multiple tests. Each of those tests will assert that something expected happens as it should, given certain input.

The point of having the tests so narrowly focused is so that when you (inevitably) break a method accidentally when refactoring, or changing some underlying code, your failed test will give you a very clear idea of what is going wrong.

Trying to test a complex series of expectations at once (in one test) reduces/removes that benefit.

Also keep in mind that just because you have 'massive hierarchies' does not mean your tests will be horribly more complex, individually. It does probably mean you will have many more tests, though. But ultimately, a test isn't much more complex because you expect 10,000 results each containing X, Y or Z - or just 10.

Comment: It's not that you should only have one assert, more that you should only test one aspect per unit test

Comment: Hi Andrew thanks for the response. I think what's forced me to think about this, is the combination of analysis of data and readyness of debugging (debug without running though all the forms, just cut to the code), has somewhat overshadowed what the tests actually *do*. It's a simple test to call a raft of very complex procedures, which explains why my tests don't feel effective. Also in my company, we do 3 months of user and functional testing at a time so real life tests are done a long time after the code is written. Good points from both of you I'll take it on board, thanks!

Comment: @Kev: You are absolutely correct, of course. In practice for me, that has always meant a single Assert and sometimes I find it easier to explain to people that way, but I should have worded that differently for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

While I think your approach of building a testing harness and doing forms of automated UI testing is useful it is very much NOT a "unit test"

There are several software packages out there that will simulate UI usage and even do some level of tracking, building your own that suits your needs seems fine to me. But I would caution that you don't confuse this with unit testing.

As Andrew said unit testing is all about testing small pieces of functionality in simplistic tests. Your example of x = y + 1 is oversimplified. The goal of unit testing, IMO, is to develop a suite of "baseline" tests that will verify that your assumptions you made 6 months ago about how **some method** works still holds true today.

When your unit tests become so large and complicated that they become a maintenance task in their own right then you have missed the whole point. "You're doing it all wrong" as they say.

Given your description of what you built it sounds like you have built a whole other program that you will have to deal with. If you happen to introduce a bug in this new testing system you will generate bad data and that could cause you to hunt down bugs that don't actually exist.

With a unit test you purposely want to keep them short and simple to avoid this problem. If your unit tests become unwieldy they become a chore. When they become a chore they start to get ignored and at that point you have lost the battle.

Comment: Excellent points there, I have replied to Andrew saying about the relatively low complexity of my "unit test" and high complexity of the code it testing. (I agree I was being a bit exagerrative with my example :)). I also agree with you about the packages for UI automated testing, they're difficult and complicated, and quite frankly we don't need them. Perhaps rationalising my "unit tests" into smaller bits of functionality would help, and the idea of being able to test code 6 months on is very appealing. Thanks for your input!